# A bounded set A has volume iff the boundary of A has measure zero - relax to content zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have a theorem in my book which reads

"A bounded set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ has volume iff the $bd(A)$ has measure zero"

I know however that if a set $B$ is compact, then measure zero implies content zero (because the countable cover has a finite sub-cover).

I know that the boundary of a set $B$, $bd(B)$ is closed because it is the intersection of the closure of two sets.

I know that if $B$ is bounded, then $bd(B)$ is bounded.

I know from the Heine-Borel theorem that a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact.

From the above it follows that $bd(A)$ is compact. So is it possible to relax the theorem in my book to

"A bounded set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ has volume iff the $bd(A)$ has *content* zero"

If so, I'm wondering why they didn't state the theorem using content in the first place.

Comment: Ẁhat do you mean by "has volume"?

Comment: $A$ has volume if the characteristic function $1_{A}$ is integrable

Comment: Can you elaborate on the definition of "volume"? Certainly a point has zero boundary and zero volume, so I'm assuming the statement means something like "is measurable". In the case of Lebesgue measure, this follows since the interior is always measurable, and the portion of the set not in the interior is in the boundary. Since the boundary has measure zero, by the completeness of the Lebesue measure, all subsets of the boundary are measurable. So, the set is composed of an interior which is measurable, and a noninterior which has measure zero.

Comment: @Lindon : Ah. You mean that $A$ is measurable with finite volume. But the indicator function of $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ is definitely measurable, its integral is $0$ and $\mathrm{bd}(\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]) = [0,1]$ does not have measure zero. Is there something I'm missing? Maybe this theorem is just an "if"?

Comment: Maybe they are referring to the Jordan measure?

Comment: As shown, a compact set of (Lebesgue) measure zero is of (Jordan) content zero, but measure theory is a place where manipulations are much easier a.e. The properties of measure is richer and deeper.